# bitmap displayed badly in different devices

Tags: android, bitmap

i have a bitmap, that is perfectly displayed inside my 7'' inch tablet, but different in other devices, it is a screen issue, but i don't understand how to fix.

i retrieve this bitmap, by URL in this way

```
URL url = new URL(...);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
overlay = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
connection.disconnect();
```

and after i do this

```
bitmapMarker = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.marker);
newMarker = bitmapMarker.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
canvas = new Canvas(newMarker);
canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, 14, 8, null);****** -> THIS CANVAS IS NOT DISPLAYED WELL IN DIFFERENT DEVICES***********
marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).title(title).snippet(snippetText).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(newMarker)));
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify? What does "not displaying well" look like?

Comment: @o0rebelious0o wait i' m updating my question.

Comment: And you are drawing with a canvas form an `ImageView`?  If that's the case, you could simply assign the `Bitmap` to the `ImageView` and then `setScaleType` to an appropriate value for filling the screen as you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Can you change

```
canvas = new Canvas(newMarker);
canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, 14, 8, null);****** -> THIS CANVAS IS NOT DISPLAYED WELL IN DIFFERENT DEVICES***********
```

to

```
canvas = new Canvas(newMarker);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
paint.setDither(true);
canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, 14, 8, paint);
```

and see if that fixes the issue?  I think android by default on some platforms will scale to fill, but not on others.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the android device size resolutions.  Each device knows which resolution it uses. By using a method that can get one of the images based on the resolution of the current device, you can get differently sized images that are appropriate for the current device.

```
getImage(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi);
```

For learning more about supporting different screens, [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) is a good place to start.  At the very least pay attention to the ratios between the different screen sizes for scaling purposes (i.e. mdpi is 25% the size of xxxhpdi).

Comment: well i' m retrieving the image via URL, this is not an image taken inside the drawable folder...

Comment: What I mean is that you can have several URLs.  Each one has a differently scaled image at it.  You can retrieve the correct one by using this message. I should have asked, is it a domain that you are free to add to?

Comment: where should i have to modify my code, to accomplish what you are saying?

Comment: All that will need to change is which URL you load from based on the device's density.  I would accomplish this by assigning to your url variable based on a switch statement on the densityDpi.  Then continue as you did before and it should work.

If you are open to using external libraries both Picasso and 9-Patch are good for loading from URLs.  I've never used 9-Patch, but have heard many recommendations.  I've used Picasso however and it makes the task you're trying to accomplish quite a bit easier. You simply load into a predefined xml frame.